# How to change custom admin menu?

Tags: function, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created an admin menu in wordpress with these functions:

```
function list_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 'My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'administrator', 'mylist', 'list_page', plugins_url('favicon.png'), 24);
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'list_menu');

function add_menu(){
    add_submenu_page( 'mylist', 'Add New', 'Add New', 'administrator', 'add_new_page', 'add_page');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_menu');
```

But it create a menu with duplicate value in the menu like this:

[image]

Is there a way to let the menu like this:

```
=> My Plugin
===> All Posts
===> Add New
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you plz try this code.

```
<?php 
function edit_admin_menus() {
    global $menu, $submenu;   
    $menu[24][0] = 'My Plugin'; // TO change admin parent menu
    $submenu['mylist'][0][0] = 'All Posts'; // To change child menu of "My Plugin" parent
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'edit_admin_menus' );
?>
```

Thanks.